# Flask SocketIO - CORS issue

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cors, flask-socketio

I'm trying to use Flask-SocketIO to add websocket functionality to my application.

My application architecture is heavily decoupled and as a result I want to use a different set of servers for handling the websocket stuff. However, in my testing I'm using the same server with just different ports.

When I try and connect in JavaScript with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect("http://dev.example.com:8000");
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });
</script>
```

I get the error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://dev.example.com:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1442224745873. (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

So to mitigate this, I did some CORS stuff and added the `crossorigin` defined here: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/

I won't post the code for the decorator as I haven't changed it from what is on the above webpage.

And then on my endpoint, I've used the decorator:

```
@app.route('/socket/')
@crossdomain(origin='http://dev.example.com:8000', headers='Content-Type')
def socket():
    return render_template('socket.html')
```

I've also tried:

```
@app.route('/socket/')
@crossdomain(origin='*', headers='Content-Type')
def socket():
    return render_template('socket.html')
```

And in the HTTP response headers of loading the /socket/ endpoint I can see the headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:HEAD, OPTIONS, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://dev.example.com:8000
Access-Control-Max-Age:21600
Content-Length:448
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 14 Sep 2015 10:20:09 GMT
Server:Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.9
```

But I still get the CORS error. Anyone got any ideas? :)

Comment: In the actual Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, you're putting the origin form which the request is being made, right? Including the actual port number. Because as written in your code snippet, the origin you've put in your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is the same as the origin of the server itself to which the request is being sent. And that would be wrong. Because it needs to be the origin of the other server, the requesting server.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was running the server on localhost as opposed to 0.0.0.0. Not sure why this gave me a CORS error but it resolved the problem.